# Copy workbook name to a cell in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search for an open file named "OTIF"[...].

When the macro finds the workbook, it should paste the file name into "sheet1" Cell A1 in another workbook (wb2).

```
Sub Filename()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 4) = "OTIF" Then
        Set Wb1 = wB
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
End If

With wb2.Sheets("AAA")
    .Range("A1").Value = Dir(Wb1.FullName)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox "DONE!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you Try the debug mode and the value for `wB.Name`. I think Workbook name also contains the extension. Thanks

Comment: @Bluesector I checked there is nothing error in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code and it can be simplified like below.

```
Sub Filename()
Dim wB As Workbook
For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 4) = "OTIF" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AAA").Range("A1").Value = wB.FullName
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox "DONE!"
End Sub
```

Comment: No filename in A1 :-(

Comment: @Bluesector Did you check AAA sheet, cell A1? I have tested this code by using dummies.

Comment: The Macro is stored in the same file as sheet "AAA". The "OTIF" File is open. Still nothing in A1.

Comment: Can you step through the code and see if it is entering `If....Loop` and executing this line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AAA").Range("A1").Value = wB.FullName`.

Comment: the code skips ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AAA").Range("A1").Value = wB.FullName... Why? The file is open.

Comment: By skipping the line do you mean that the if statement never meets a true condition? Might sound silly, but are you certain the filename pattern is correct and the files are all caps? Maybe convert to all uppercase in the if statement to be safe? UCase(Left(wB.Name, 4))

Comment: Somehow not the macro works... I think this was an excel error.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve with

```
Dir(Wb1.FullName)
```

That is the source of your problem. Just delete the `Dir` and the `()` and its running: `.Range("A1").Value = Wb1.FullName`

Comment: Now he is highlighting me With wb2.Sheets("AAA") - starting to get insane :-D

Comment: Weird ^^ What is the error? You need to make sure, that the workbook you are starting the macro from does contain a sheet called "AAA".

Comment: Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. Unfortunately, the workbook contains the sheet.

Comment: Do you have stored the macro in the workbook, which contains the sheet "AAA"? If it's stored in your PERSONAL.XLSB, the error might be caused by this. In that case you need to adapt this line of code: `Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook`

Comment: the macro is stored in the same workbook. I changed the position of the "End if" and I don't get an error anymore. But I still can't get the file name in the cell. Nothing.

Comment: Step through the code with F8 and check the variables wb1 and wb2 during runtime. The code still works for me with the changes though.

Answer (score 0):

***Full Edited code:***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filename()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = wb2.Worksheets("AAA")
On Error GoTo 0
If ws Is Nothing Then ' make sure "AAA" sheet exists
    MsgBox "AAA sheet does not exist, or has been renamed", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 4) = "OTIF" Then
        ' for DEBUG ONLY
        ws.Range("A1").Value = wB.Sheets.Count

        ' 2nd Debug option
        ws.Range("A1").Value = "Test"

       ' ws.Range("A1").Value = wB.Name

        MsgBox "DONE!"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. Hm :-/

Comment: @bluesector: Remove `WIth` and `End With`

Comment: Had to change the position of the "End if". Now I don't get an error anymore. Unfortunately, still doesn't copy any file name in the cell.

Comment: Hey thank you. No Error - but also no File Name :-(. What could cause this.

Comment: OTIF File is open. Macro is stored in the workbook that has the sheet 'AAA' - Still nothing in A1...

Comment: @Bluesector try edited code, added some DEBUG options

Comment: Nothing happens. Not even a message :/

Comment: @Bluesector  so you are not passing the If criteria

Comment: I only have one xlsm file open. This file contains the "AAA" sheet. The other XLS file is the OTIF one